# Estimate unknown function block using neural networks

Tags: regression, neural-networks, classification, nonlinear-regression

I have a function block that outputs a single-value when fed with a signal (a measurement taken from a sensor) containing a 1000 time points.
A similar case would be a function block that computes the mean value of the signal. The difference being I don't know what the function is in my case.

I also have a dataset of records of about 20000 signals (each containing a 1000 time points) and their corresponding 20000 values outputted by my function block.

What I'm looking for is a way that allows me to determine this function block to be able to get an estimate of this outputted single-value for inputs other than the ones I already have in my dataset. My knowledge about what this function might be is very limited.

Note that I'm not looking to predict or forecast time series data (signal in my case).

I looked at (nonlinear) regression but, unless I'm mistaken, my problem doesn't seem like a regression problem to me. If I had to write a mathematical description for it considering a single input signal $\vec{x} (1000\times1)$ and its corresponding outputted single-valued parameter $p$ I would write:
$$
\min_{f, \vec{\theta}} |p -  f(\vec{x}, \vec{\theta})|
$$
where $f$ is the unknown function and $\vec{\theta}$ some vector parameter of this function.

I thought that a neural network might help with that. I'm not sure, however, how to go about implementing this.
Any help is appreciated.